# print to view result of BigQuery query

Tags: python, flask, google-bigquery, flask-restful

I have a BigQuery query inside a function as follows:

```
def get_data_from_bigquery():
    """query bigquery to get data to import to PSQL"""
    app_id = get_app_id()
    bq = bigquery.Client(project=app_id)
    query = """SELECT * FROM `Backup.Prod_UserUserMetadata`"""
    query_job = bq.query(query)
    data = query_job.result()
    rows = list(data)
    print(rows)
    return rows
```

I have my route as follows:

```
@app.route('/azure-import-data')
def print_data():
    return 'This is the data:\n \n'
```

The function `get_data_from_bigquery()` is being called inside my `get()` function inside the following class:

```
class AzureImportProcess(Resource):
    def get(self):
        get_data_from_bigquery()
...
api.add_resource(AzureImportProcess, '/azure-import-data')
```

The `print(rows)` function doesn't seem to work since it's not being printed either on Cloud Console or in the browser. Is there any other way I could print the data to see how it's being formatted?

Comment: It does not look like you are calling the function `get_data_from_bigquery` in your routing function. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: Post Updated @Abdou

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you do not need the the `print` statement inside the `get_data_from_bigquery` function. Second, the `get` function needs to have a `return` statement in order for something to show.

Edit the function definition as follows:

```
def get_data_from_bigquery():
    """query bigquery to get data to import to PSQL"""
    app_id = get_app_id()
    bq = bigquery.Client(project=app_id)
    query = """SELECT * FROM `Backup.Prod_UserUserMetadata`"""
    query_job = bq.query(query)
    data = query_job.result()
    rows = list(data)
    return rows
```

Edit the `Resource` class definition as follows:

```
class AzureImportProcess(Resource):
    def get(self):
        bq_data = get_data_from_bigquery()
        return 'This is the data:\n \n{}'.format(bq_data)
```

Now you can add your resource to the `API` object:

```
api.add_resource(AzureImportProcess, '/azure-import-data')
```

You don't need to define the `print_data` function here, unless you are dealing with more complicated API's.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It is probably trying to print the data (52k rows total) but it throws the following exception: `Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 268 MB after servicing 0 requests total`

Comment: That's neither a `Flask` nor `flask_restful` error. It has to do with `App Engine`. Reduce the query something like `"""SELECT * FROM Backup.Prod_UserUserMetadata LIMIT 100"""` to make sure that the answer actually works. Once you're sure that it works, then you can figure out how to deal with your memory issues.